# _id object id in subdocument VS new collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

The point is that, I am developing a nodejs rest api and I am not sure of the best way of making some relations between entities. I have a main entity that will hold most of the information (simple properties as strings, numbers, dates.... and sub-document/s). All this information is unique of each main document, so my first approach was creating only  one document with several sub-documents or sub-documents arrays. But I should be able to perform a post/get/put/delete of some of this subdocuments individually. So , in summary my question is. 
which is better thinking in terms of performance?

Maybe with an example I can explain myself in a better way. Always thinking and taking in consideration that all sub-documents are not shared with any other main document.

One collection example:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxx"),
    "prop1": "some text",
    "number2": 1,
    subDocumentsArr: [
        { 
            "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxx"),
            "someSubDocumentProp": "Some text"
        },
        { 
            "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxx"),
            "someSubDocumentProp": "More text"
        }
    ]
}
```

VS

Two collections example:

```
(first collection)

{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxxx"),
    "prop1": "some text",
    "number2": 1,
    subDocumentsArr: [ "subdoc1", "subdoc2" ]
}


(second collection)
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("subdoc1"),
        "someSubDocumentProp": "Some text"
    }
    { 
        "_id": ObjectId("subdoc2"),
        "someSubDocumentProp": "More text"
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subdocuments` is small, embed it. It'll be much faster to query & update. A major part of document-based databases is that you really want to encapsulate things in as few documents as possible -- that's how they're designed to be used.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1 has some good advice about rules of thumb you can use.

Comment: thanks for your answer & additional info. I supose that if the subdocuments have thousens of properties for each document or the sum of all of them, would become a huge json file will be a problem (not my case) in the future, but if the subdocuments have only as much 50 properties, then it woun´t be a problem for me isn't it? Aditionaly and based on the information link you posted, there is a sentence "you have no way of accessing the embedded details as stand-alone entities" when embedding docs then my reflexion is that is not a good practice my case..

Comment: If you need to have queries like "find all subdocuments that have X and Y" rather than "find all *container* documents that have subdocuments that have X and Y" the embedding pattern does break down a little bit and you'd have to start either using aggregations, app-side processing, or denormalizing your data in a way that makes those queries possible. (This is what that article was referring to when they said "there's no way to access..." they really mean "there's no easy way to query by & only return matching subdocuments")

Comment: Given that "all sub-documents are not shared with any other main document," embedding will normally be the way to go